# Atelier B animate with ProB Error while parsing machine: end_of_file

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm having problems with animating the machines using prob. When i select animate with ProB(TCL/TK) in Atelier B, I get this error

```
Make sure Java Runtime 7 or newer is installed
 the Java B parser (probcliparser.jar) cannot be launched:  c:/prob//lib/probcliparser.jar

 Error while parsing machine:  end_of_file
```

My java installation works fine and it's java version "1.8.0_65".

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at web sites such as [Installation — ProB Documentation](https://www3.hhu.de/stups/prob/index.php/Installation)?  It sounds as if your jar file is incomplete.  I've retagged the question with Tcl/Tk since it is more appropriate than the [tag:b] tag, which applies to the language B, a predecessor to C.

Comment: The problem was with access rights. I have installed my ProB in C drive. Running it as administrator solved the problem,

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with access rights. I have installed my ProB in C drive. Running it as administrator solved the problem.
Just leaving it here if anyone else gets this same problem.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I was stuck hours with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had an error with the probcliparser.jar within ProB itself when opening the machine file.
ProB would stop responding.
[image]

Using the "Check Java and Parser Version" command in the Debug Menu would state:

[image]

I was using Java 15.0.2.

**Changing the Java version to 1.8.0 resolved the issue** for me, despite the false positive that ProB gave stating that Java 15 was compatible.

You can specify the path to your correct JDK from within ProB itself by going to
Preferences > All Preferences (alphabetical)
and changing the value of `JAVA_PATH`.

Alternatively, if you're on Windows, you can modify your Environment PATH Variables to give the correct JDK a higher priority by moving it up the list. (Note that this will likely affect all the programs using the `java` command)